Why does LiDAR shift and looses localization during robot rotation at high velocities, and how to prevent it?
I am working with a mobile robot equipped with a LiDAR sensor, and I've encountered an issue where the LiDAR seems to shift or misalign with the robot's frame during rotations at higher velocities and looses localization. Specifically, the issue occurs when the robot's max_vel_x and max_vel_theta are set above 0.6, and it happens shortly after the robot starts rotating. The LiDAR alignment to the map seems to stabilize after a few seconds, but the temporary misalignment is causing some issues with localization and mapping.
Here are some details about my setup:   
    LiDAR model: SLAMTEC RPLiDAR S2E - 2nos   
    System environment: ros2 Humble
param.yaml:
    amcl:
      ros__parameters:
        use_sim_time: False
        alpha1: 2.0
        alpha2: 1.0
        alpha3: 1.0
        alpha4: 2.0
        alpha5: 0.2
        base_frame_id: "base_footprint"
        beam_skip_distance: 0.5
        beam_skip_error_threshold: 0.9
        beam_skip_threshold: 0.3
        do_beamskip: false
        global_frame_id: "map"
        lambda_short: 0.1
        laser_likelihood_max_dist: 2.0
        laser_max_range: -1.0
        laser_min_range: -1.0
        laser_model_type: "likelihood_field"
        max_beams: 60
        max_particles: 2000
        min_particles: 500
        odom_frame_id: "odom"
        pf_err: 0.05
        pf_z: 0.99
        recovery_alpha_fast: 0.0
        recovery_alpha_slow: 0.0
        resample_interval: 1
        robot_model_type: "nav2_amcl::DifferentialMotionModel"
        save_pose_rate: 0.5
        initial_pose: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
        set_initial_pose: True
        sigma_hit: 0.2
        tf_broadcast: true
        transform_tolerance: 0.2
        update_min_a: 0.01
        update_min_d: 0.01
        z_hit: 0.5
        z_max: 0.05
        z_rand: 0.5
        z_short: 0.05
        scan_topic: scan    
    amcl_map_client:
      ros__parameters:
        use_sim_time: False    
    amcl_rclcpp_node:
      ros__parameters:
        use_sim_time: False    
    bt_navigator:
      ros__parameters:
        use_sim_time: False
        global_frame: map
        robot_base_frame: base_link
        odom_topic: /odom
        default_bt_xml_filename: "navigate_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml"
        bt_loop_duration: 10
        default_server_timeout: 20
        enable_groot_monitoring: True
        groot_zmq_publisher_port: 1666
        groot_zmq_server_port: 1667
        plugin_lib_names:
        - nav2_compute_path_to_pose_action_bt_node
        - nav2_compute_path_through_poses_action_bt_node
        - nav2_follow_path_action_bt_node
        - nav2_back_up_action_bt_node
        - nav2_spin_action_bt_node
        - nav2_wait_action_bt_node
        - nav2_clear_costmap_service_bt_node
        - nav2_is_stuck_condition_bt_node
        - nav2_goal_reached_condition_bt_node
        - nav2_goal_updated_condition_bt_node
        - nav2_initial_pose_received_condition_bt_node
        - nav2_reinitialize_global_localization_service_bt_node
        - nav2_rate_controller_bt_node
        - nav2_distance_controller_bt_node
        - nav2_speed_controller_bt_node
        - nav2_truncate_path_action_bt_node
        - nav2_goal_updater_node_bt_node
        - nav2_recovery_node_bt_node
        - nav2_pipeline_sequence_bt_node
        - nav2_round_robin_node_bt_node
        - nav2_transform_available_condition_bt_node
        - nav2_time_expired_condition_bt_node
        - nav2_distance_traveled_condition_bt_node
        - nav2_single_trigger_bt_node
        - nav2_is_battery_low_condition_bt_node
        - nav2_navigate_through_poses_action_bt_node
        - nav2_navigate_to_pose_action_bt_node
        - nav2_remove_passed_goals_action_bt_node
        - nav2_planner_selector_bt_node
        - nav2_controller_selector_bt_node
        - nav2_goal_checker_selector_bt_node    
    bt_navigator_rclcpp_node:
      ros__parameters:
        use_sim_time: False    
    controller_server:
      ros__parameters:
        use_sim_time: true
        controller_frequency: 10.0
        min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
        min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.5
        min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.001
        failure_tolerance: 10.0
        progress_checker_plugin: "progress_checker"
        goal_checker_plugins: ["general_goal_checker"]
        controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]    
        progress_checker:
          plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker"
          required_movement_radius: 0.5
          movement_time_allowance: 10.0    
        general_goal_checker:
          stateful: True
          plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
          xy_goal_tolerance: 0.3
          yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.17    
        FollowPath:
          plugin: "dwb_core::DWBLocalPlanner"
          debug_trajectory_details: True
          min_vel_x: -0.0
          min_vel_y: 0.0
          max_vel_x: 0.6  
          max_vel_y: 0.0
          max_vel_theta: 0.6
          min_speed_xy: 0.0
          max_speed_xy: 0.62
          min_speed_theta: 0.05
          acc_lim_x: 2.5
          acc_lim_y: 0.0
          acc_lim_theta: 4.0
          decel_lim_x: -2.5
          decel_lim_y: 0.0
          decel_lim_theta: -3.8 
          vx_samples: 200
          vy_samples: 0 
          vtheta_samples: 40
          sim_time: 1.5
          linear_granularity: 0.05
          angular_granularity: 0.025
          transform_tolerance: 0.3
          xy_goal_tolerance: 0.3
          trans_stopped_velocity: 0.25
          short_circuit_trajectory_evaluation: True
          stateful: True
          critics: ["RotateToGoal", "Oscillation", "BaseObstacle", "GoalAlign", "PathAlign", "PathDist", "GoalDist"]
          BaseObstacle.scale: 0.02
          PathAlign.scale: 32.0
          PathAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.325
          GoalAlign.scale: 24.0
          GoalAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.325
          PathDist.scale: 32.0
          GoalDist.scale: 20.0
          RotateToGoal.scale: 32.0
          RotateToGoal.slowing_factor: 5.0
          RotateToGoal.lookahead_time: -1.0          
    controller_server_rclcpp_node:
      ros__parameters:
        use_sim_time: False    
    local_costmap:
      local_costmap:
        ros__parameters:
          update_frequency: 10.0
          publish_frequency: 5.0
          global_frame: map
          robot_base_frame: base_footprint
          use_sim_time: False
          rolling_window: true
          width: 5
          height: 5
          resolution: 0.1
          robot_radius: 0.42
          plugins: ["obstacle_layer", "voxel_layer", "inflation_layer"]
          inflation_layer:
            plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
            cost_scaling_factor: 15.0
            inflation_radius: 0.2
          obstacle_layer:
            plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
            enabled: True
            inflation_radius: 0.1     
            observation_sources: lidar_front_right/scan lidar_rear_left/scan
            lidar_front_right/scan:
              topic: /lidar_front_right/scan
              max_obstacle_height: 2.0
              clearing: True
              marking: True
              data_type: "LaserScan"
            lidar_rear_left/scan:
              topic: /lidar_rear_left/scan
              max_obstacle_height: 2.0
              clearing: True
              marking: True
              data_type: "LaserScan"
          voxel_layer:
            plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"
            enabled: True
            publish_voxel_map: True
            origin_z: 0.0
            z_resolution: 0.05
            z_voxels: 16
            max_obstacle_height: 2.0
            mark_threshold: 0
            observation_sources: lidar_front_right/scan lidar_rear_left/scan
            lidar_front_right/scan:
              topic: /lidar_front_right/scan
              max_obstacle_height: 2.0
              clearing: True
              marking: True
              data_type: "LaserScan"
              raytrace_max_range: 5.0
              raytrace_min_range: 0.0
              obstacle_max_range: 5.0
              obstacle_min_range: 0.0
            lidar_rear_left/scan:
              topic: /lidar_rear_left/scan
              max_obstacle_height: 2.0
              clearing: True
              marking: True
              data_type: "LaserScan"
              raytrace_max_range: 6.0
              raytrace_min_range: 0.0
              obstacle_max_range: 5.0
              obstacle_min_range: 0.0
          static_layer:
            map_subscribe_transient_local: True
          always_send_full_costmap: True    
    global_costmap:
      global_costmap:
        ros__parameters:
          update_frequency: 10.0
          publish_frequency: 5.0
          global_frame: map
          robot_base_frame: base_footprint
          use_sim_time: false
          robot_radius: 0.42
          resolution: 0.05
          track_unknown_space: true
          plugins: ["static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "voxel_layer", "inflation_layer"]
          obstacle_layer:
            plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
            enabled: True
            inflation_radius: 0.6
            observation_sources: lidar_front_right/scan lidar_rear_left/scan
            lidar_front_right/scan:
              topic: /lidar_front_right/scan
              max_obstacle_height: 2.0
              clearing: True
              marking: True
              data_type: "LaserScan"
              raytrace_max_range: 6.0
              raytrace_min_range: 0.0
              obstacle_max_range: 5.0
              obstacle_min_range: 0.0
            lidar_rear_left/scan:
              topic: /lidar_rear_left/scan
              max_obstacle_height: 2.0
              clearing: True
              marking: True
              data_type: "LaserScan"
              raytrace_max_range: 6.0
              raytrace_min_range: 0.0
              obstacle_max_range: 5.0
              obstacle_min_range: 0.0
          voxel_layer:  
            plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"
            enabled: True
            publish_voxel_map: True
            origin_z: 0.0
            z_resolution: 0.05
            z_voxels: 16
            max_obstacle_height: 2.0
            mark_threshold: 0
            observation_sources: lidar_front_right/scan lidar_rear_left/scan
            lidar_front_right/scan:
              topic: /lidar_front_right/scan
              max_obstacle_height: 2.0
              clearing: True
              marking: True
              data_type: "LaserScan"
              raytrace_max_range: 5.0
              raytrace_min_range: 0.0
              obstacle_max_range: 5.0
              obstacle_min_range: 0.0
            lidar_rear_left/scan:
              topic: /lidar_rear_left/scan
              max_obstacle_height: 2.0
              clearing: True
              marking: True
              data_type: "LaserScan"
              raytrace_max_range: 5.0
              raytrace_min_range: 0.0
              obstacle_max_range: 5.0
              obstacle_min_range: 0.0
          static_layer:
            plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
            map_subscribe_transient_local: True
          inflation_layer:
            plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
            cost_scaling_factor: 25.0
            inflation_radius: 0.6
          always_send_full_costmap: True
      global_costmap_client:
        ros__parameters:
          use_sim_time: False
      global_costmap_rclcpp_node:
        ros__parameters:
          use_sim_time: False    
    map_server:
      ros__parameters:
        use_sim_time: False
        yaml_filename: "em3.yaml"    
    map_saver:
      ros__parameters:
        use_sim_time: False
        save_map_timeout: 5000  
        free_thresh_default: 0.25
        occupied_thresh_default: 0.65
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True    
    planner_server:
      ros__parameters:
        expected_planner_frequency: 1.0
        use_sim_time: False
        planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
        GridBased:
          plugin: "nav2_navfn_planner/NavfnPlanner"
          tolerance: 1.0  #foxy 1.0
          use_astar: true  #foxy true
          allow_unknown: true    
    planner_server_rclcpp_node:
      ros__parameters:
        use_sim_time: False    
    recoveries_server:
      ros__parameters:
        costmap_topic: local_costmap/costmap_raw
        footprint_topic: local_costmap/published_footprint
        cycle_frequency: 1.0
        recovery_plugins: ["spin", "backup", "wait"]
        spin:
          plugin: "nav2_recoveries/Spin"
        backup:
          plugin: "nav2_recoveries/BackUp"
        wait:
          plugin: "nav2_recoveries/Wait"
        global_frame: odom
        robot_base_frame: base_footprint
        transform_timeout: 0.1
        use_sim_time: false
        simulate_ahead_time: 2.0
        max_rotational_vel: 0.3 
        min_rotational_vel: 0.05
        rotational_acc_lim: 1.2   
    robot_state_publisher:
      ros__parameters:
        use_sim_time: False    
    waypoint_follower:
      ros__parameters:
        loop_rate: 2000  ####20
        stop_on_failure: false
        waypoint_task_executor_plugin: "wait_at_waypoint"   
        wait_at_waypoint:
          plugin: "nav2_waypoint_follower::WaitAtWaypoint"
          enabled: True
          waypoint_pause_duration: 200
    smoother_server:
      ros__parameters:
        # General parameters
        update_rate: 20.0    
        smoother_type: "velocity_smoother"
        velocity_smoother:
          type: "nav2_smoother::VelocitySmoother"
          lookahead_time: 0.5
          samples: 10
          min_samples: 5
          max_samples: 20
          alpha: 0.8
          beta: 0.2
          max_velocity_xy: 0.5
          max_velocity_theta: 0.5
          smoothing_frequency: 80.0
        motion_model_for_search: "DifferentialDrive"
        pose_distance: 0.25
        publish_predicted_path: false
        publish_filtered_path: false    
    realsense_node:
      ros__parameters:
        topics:
          color:
            image: "/camera/color/image_raw"
            camera_info: "/camera/color/camera_info"
          depth:
            image: "/camera/depth/image_rect_raw"
          infra1:
            image: "/camera/infra1/image_rect_raw"
          infra2:
            image: "/camera/infra2/image_rect_raw"
        depth_scale_meters: 0.001
    behavior_server:
      ros__parameters:
        bond_disable_heartbeat_timeout: true
        backup.plugin: nav2_behaviors/BackUp
        behavior_plugins:
          - spin
          - backup
          - drive_on_heading
          - wait
        costmap_topic: local_costmap/costmap_raw
        cycle_frequency: 20.0
        drive_on_heading.plugin: nav2_behaviors/DriveOnHeading
        footprint_topic: local_costmap/published_footprint
        global_frame: odom
        max_rotational_vel: 0.1
        min_rotational_vel: 0.05
        robot_base_frame: base_link
        rotational_acc_lim: 2.0
        simulate_ahead_time: 2.0
        spin.plugin: nav2_behaviors/Spin
        transform_tolerance: 0.5
        use_sim_time: false
        wait.plugin: nav2_behaviors/Wait        
    velocity_smoother:
      ros__parameters:
        bond_disable_heartbeat_timeout: true
        feedback: OPEN_LOOP
        odom_duration: 0.1
        odom_topic: /odom
        scale_velocities: true
        smoothing_frequency: 150.0
        use_sim_time: False
        velocity_timeout: 1.0

ekf config file
ekf_filter_node:
ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: false
    frequency: 30.0

    sensor_timeout: 0.1

    two_d_mode: true

    transform_time_offset: 0.0

    transform_timeout: 0.0

    print_diagnostics: true

    debug: false

    debug_out_file: /path/to/debug/file.txt

    publish_tf: false

    publish_acceleration: false

    map_frame: map                 
    odom_frame: /odom                
    base_link_frame: /base_footprint 
    world_frame: /odom                

    odom0: /odom

    odom0_config: [true, true, true,
                   false, false, true,
                   true,  true,  true,
                   false, false, false,
                   false, false, false]

    odom0_queue_size: 2

    odom0_nodelay: false

    odom0_differential: false
    odom0_relative: true

    odom0_pose_rejection_threshold: 5.0
    odom0_twist_rejection_threshold: 1.0

    imu0: /imu_data
    imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                  true,  true,  false,
                  true, true, true,
                  true,  true,  true,
                  true,  true,  true]
    
    imu0_nodelay: false
    imu0_differential: false
    imu0_relative: true
    imu0_queue_size: 7
    imu0_pose_rejection_threshold: 0.8                 
    imu0_twist_rejection_threshold: 0.8                
    imu0_linear_acceleration_rejection_threshold: 0.8  

    imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

    use_control: false

    stamped_control: false

    control_timeout: 0.2

    control_config: [true, false, false, false, false, true]

    acceleration_limits: [1.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.4]

    deceleration_limits: [1.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.5]

    acceleration_gains: [0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.9]

    deceleration_gains: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]

    process_noise_covariance: [0.05,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.05,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.06,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.03,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.03,   0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.06,   0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.025,   0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.025,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.04,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.01,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.01,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.02,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.01,   0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.01,   0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.015]

    initial_estimate_covariance: [1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     1e-9,    0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     1e-9,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    1e-9]

here i added the param and ekf.yaml files and rviz running video: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1415Q_JOubg6PHrCnw_o0JKxXoDoCEx71?usp=sharing
Could this behavior be caused by motion distortion, sensor fusion issues, or something else related to velocity and sensor calibration? How can I prevent the LiDAR shift from happening during rotations at higher velocities?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

In my experience that is caused by poor odometry coming from your robot.
There is a simple way for you to check it, for now forget about AMCL, just start your robot without localization. Using RVIZ set the fixed frame to your robot's odometry frame and visualize the laser with a long decay time (around 10 seconds would do).
Drive the robot straight down a hallway. The laser scans of the hallway should stay straight. If you see them move a lot, it means your odometry is poor (specifically the size of the tires in your configuration does not match the size of the tires on the real robot).
In the same way, rotate the robot in place. The laser scans should stay consistent. If you see them rotate (in either the same direction or the opposite rotational direction) means you odometry is poor (specifically the separation between the wheels in your configuration does not match the wheel separation on the real robot).
I hope this helps

thanks for replay @MartinPeris i have tested i added tested video kindly verify it
Link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1O4nIPJ7vTGfFQLzspBhovk03xjkOyLa2?usp=sharing

@Manoj_Prabha the video belongs in the question, not in a comment ... please add it there

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1O4nIPJ7vTGfFQLzspBhovk03xjkOyLa2?usp=sharing

As you can see in "Screencast from 11-20-2024 03:06:26 PM.webm" as the robot rotates clockwise the laser scans start to add counter-clockwise. That would hint me to check the tread size on your differential drive control configuration

I have checked tread size its all perfect...

While the tread size may appear correct based on measurements or specifications, in practice it is rarely perfect due to real-world factors. Manufacturing tolerances, slight imperfections, wheel wear, and even floor conditions can cause small discrepancies in the actual tread width. These tiny variations can significantly impact odometry calculations, especially during rotational movements. Therefore, it's important to empirically calibrate the tread size to account for these real-world factors and ensure accurate motion tracking.
